# SQLITE 3.9.0, Windows 10 x64 - How to import a .csv from the command line shell?

Tags: sqlite, csv, import

I can do it using the GUI (not that hard) but I really would like do to it by sqlite command lines. I've googled it and have tried everything, however nothing seems to work. Please give me a hint on this! This is the last thing I've tried:

```
CREATE TABLE 'teste3' (
'Id'    integer,
'Idade' integer,
'Sexo' text,
'Peso' integer
 );
.separator ',';
.mode csv;
.import 'C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Monografia\base_teste.csv' teste3
```

What I intended to do was to create a table ('teste3',done) and them "fill it" by importing a given .csv file. Instead, I keep getting this error message: "near ".": syntax error:". Then I tried to cut off the "." before separator, for example, but I got another error: "near "separator": syntax error:". I really don't know what to do. Thanks!

Comment: Which of these commands results in the error?

Comment: Hi CL! Thanks for replying! The "create table" works just fine. I start getting the error messages after that (from ".separator ',' to ".import").

Comment: The error messages you've shown does not match the code you've show. Show the exact sequence of commands, and `sqlite3.exe`'s output.

Comment: Thanks once again, CL, but this is the exact order of my code that I ran in DB Browser for SQLite.

Comment: Well, this was the exact order of the code that I ran at that time in DB Browser for SQLite, but two different things are happening here now. If I highlight each command and run it, I get the messages below.

For the "create table"command, the message was the following: 
Query executed successfully: CREATE TABLE 'teste3' (
'Id'    integer,
'Idade' integer,
'Sexo' text,
'Peso' integer
 ); (took 0ms)

Comment: For ".separator ',';" (without the quotes), I got:
near ".": syntax error:

For ".mode csv;":
near ".": syntax error: 

For ".import 'C:\Users\Luana\Documents\Monografia\base_teste.csv' teste3;":
near ".": syntax error:

Comment: Now if I create the table, place the cursor in ".separator',';" and hit run, I get the following log:

CREATE TABLE 'teste3' (
'Id'    integer,
'Idade' integer,
'Sexo' text,
'Peso' integer
 );
 
 .separator ',';
 .mode csv;
 .import 'C:\Users\Luana\Documents\Monografia\base_teste.csv' teste3; and the following error message:
table 'teste3' already exists:

Comment: P.S: The create table is repeated this time

Comment: I did not ask about DB Browser but the command-line shell.

Comment: Dear CL, I wrote exactly the code I used in the command line shell of the software which I downloaded from http://sqlitebrowser.org/. As you can see, there is the label "execute SQL", where I entered and executed the command lines I tried to describe so far. However, if I was not able to make myself clear, do not worry. And thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Dot commands like `.mode` and `.import` are not SQL statements; they are implemented by the [sqlite3.exe command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) (which can be [downloaded](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) from the offical SQLite site).

The *DB Browser for SQLite* is an entirely independent tool. It does not implement these dot commands; you have to use the GUI instead.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Well, since it runs "create table" with "select from" and stuff, I guess I can import a .csv file through the "execute sql" label using standard sql statements. I'm gonna take a look at this. Thanks very much for the help, CL!